# How to call and pass parameter to R function in C++?

Tags: c++, r, function

I m writing one function in R for plotting graph. I need to call this function using C++ program.

R Program (script.R)

```
genplot<-function(x,y,outfile)
{
   plot(outfile)
   plot(x,y)
   dev.off()
}
```

C++ Program (Run.cpp)

```
#include <iostream.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int x[] = (1,2,3,4,5);
   int y[] = (2,3,4,1,3);
   genplot(x,y);    #need to call r function by passing these 2 variables.
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look at using [RServe](http://www.rforge.net/Rserve/doc.html). Comes with a C++ client.

Comment: @Alert This is really very useful but there is no example showing how to use this with C++. can u pls suggest or post any example doing the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RInside`. Reading [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html) page , I come with this , But I haven't test it yet. The basic idea is to passe data to R using `Rcpp` wrappers then evalute your function as a string.

```
#include <RInside.h>  
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    RInside R(argc, argv);              // create an embedded R instance 
    int x[] = (1,2,3,4,5);
    int y[] = (2,3,4,1,3);
    R.assign(x,"x");
    R.assign(y,"y");
    R["outfile"] = "output.txt";   
    R.parseEvalQ("genplot(x,y,outfile)");           // eval init string, ignoring returns
    exit(0);
}
```